# How mechanically different is The One Ring revised edition?

Tags: edition-comparison, the-one-ring

I just ordered The One Ring RPG, but my edition (translated) is based on the first edition with two books in a sleeve box.

I looked at the Clarifications and Amendments PDF, but it is hard to say what is a Clarification and what is a an Amendment. Mostly so because I will have the translated book so the page references and text position are sometimes very different.

Are there any mechanical changes that really improves the game,  or the first edition is good as it is? Is anything "broken" in the first edition?

Comment: What language are your books translated into? This might affect the answer.

Comment: Portuguese (Brazil).

Answer (score 3):

The document lists a bunch of small changes, erratas, and corrections to abilities throughout the book. However, some of the changes actually impact the gameplay:

**Advancedment points**

Before you would gain advancedment points by succeeding or failing a skill check. Now, you only gain advancement points by succeeding a skill check.

**Endurance Recovery**

Before, characters would recover the listed values whenever they had a 8-hours period to rest. A character with an untreated injury would recover 1 point, one with treated injury 2 points, and an uninjuried character would recover 2 points plus Heart rating.

Now, those listed values are when they are recovering on a safe place (such as an inn or at home). If they are travelling, they recover poorly (slower than normal). A character with an untreated injury does not recover, one with treated injuries recover 1 point of Endurance, and an uninjuried character recovers 2 points of Endurance.

**Favoured Skills**

Those now cost about 25% less advancement points to upgrade.

**Intimidate a Foe**

Is now a much better option, the **cost of one Hope point for failing the check was removed**, and the Hate points removed was increased by one point per margin of success. An extraordinary success will remove either 4 points or the character Valour rating.

However, before, the loremaster would remove that value from all enemies, now he divides the Hate points lost between enemies however he chooses, which is somewhat balanced if you have one strong enemy with lots of Hate points grouped with many smaller enemies with few hate points.

So it was a buff/nerf depending on the situation. But the removal of the Hope point cost at failure is surely a bonus.

**Obtain a title**

You can now obtain a feud, farmstead, house, cottage or another benefit from befriending one of the settlements. This is a **new undertaking** that can be done during downtime for characters who has performed some good deeds within the territory of another Culture.

**Hazards**

Now there are **consequences** listed for every type of hazard, so the loremaster doesn't have to come up with something by herself.

As you can see, *most* of those changes are small and can be implemented if you own the first edition of the game without difficulty.